# Electrostatics: Gauss' law

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

What would happen to the flux coming out of a portion of a **charged** **conducting** sphere  if an **uncharged conductor** is brought near the sphere with **velocity v** ?take the charged and uncharged spheres to be identical.

Comment: The question is pretty clear to me, a layman. There will be hardly computable dipole effects. Instead of closing the question, maybe an answer describing this would be acceptable and useful.

Comment: Why wonder about a moving uncharged conductor? What if the uncharged conductor is distance R away? Then change the distance.  And what do you mean by "what would happen?" Obviously, the electric field between the conductors is changing.  How it changes depends on the shape of the uncharged conductor and how the velocity points.  The question is not clear.

Comment: i have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the charge on sphere is not too big to cause dielectric breakdown of air then the flux will remain the same. This is because the flux through a closed surface only depends on the net charge on the sphere which remains same in this case. But if there is an electric breakdown and charge shifts from charged to uncharged sphere then the flux will change.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the electric flux coming out of a *portion* of a charged conducting sphere when an uncharged conductor is approaching. Even though the total flux coming out of the sphere will, according to Gauss law, remain the same, the electric flux (and field strength) will be stronger in the direction of the approaching conductor. This happens because the field of the charged sphere induces charges on the conductor in the region nearest to the sphere which leads to a concentration of field lines there. The speed has no influence as long as it is not extremely high.